# Why does Enable-Mailbox show all mailbox properties when finished?

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

I have a Powershell script that creates AD Users from a CSV file and creates a mailbox in our on-premises Exchange server. The script works well, but every time it finishes the 'Enable-Mailbox' command, it outputs the mailbox properties as if 'Get-Mailbox | FL' is being called. The command is used as follows:

`Enable-Mailbox -Identity <identity> -Alias <alias> -Database <database>`

This link says that Enable-Mailbox has no output (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/management/exchange-management-shell-cmdlet-input-and-output-types), and this command is at the end of the loop, so nothing else would be outputting anything before moving on to the next user.

Can anyone shed some light on what's going on or point me in the direction to figure out why this is happening?

EDIT: I'm piping to `Out-Null` to suppress the output for now

Comment: @acro444 yeah I forgot to mention I'd be using that to suppress the output for now, thank you!

Comment: the documentation could be wrong.  I don't have access to this cmdlet to check, but what is shown in the actual PowerShell help (e.g. `Get-Help Enable-Mailbox -Full`)?  Does it list anything in the `Outputs` section?  Also, what type is actually being returned (e.g. `Enable-Mailbox | Get-Member`)?

Comment: @boxdog Powershell help lists same info as the website documentation and the type returned is `Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Directory.Management.Mailbox`. The normal output just shows the Name, Alias, Server, and ProhibitSendQuota in a table instead of the whole list of properties with their values, so perhaps the Mailbox object reacts differently in a certain context?

Comment: did you try adding `| Out-Null` to the command?